# Argument type mismatch when try to consume child class in Jersey

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I`ve write two DTOs

parent

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
public class DTO1 {
  @XmlElement
  private String field1;
...
}
```

and child

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
public class DTO2 extends DTO1 {
  @XmlElement
  private String field2;
...
}
```

and resource

```
  @POST
  @Path("/example")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public DTO2 postExample(DTO2 dto) {
    doSmth()
  }
```

Regardless of whether I am sending DTO1 or DTO2 to the body of POST, I have 500 in the response and **argument type mismatch** in log. If I change XmlRootElement name in one of the DTO, situation is changed and all work correct, I can send send DTO2 and get 200.

Can I do something to leave the same names in XmlRootElement?

I`ve try to use annotations like XmlType, write namespace, but now I do refactoring of old code and it is important to leave same protocol for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two DTOs with the same @XmlRootElement name, but with different properties, it can cause issues with XML deserialization since the XML representation of the two objects is indistinguishable. The deserializer may not know which DTO to deserialize the XML into, which can cause the argument type mismatch error that you are seeing.

One solution is to differentiate the two DTOs by using different XML element names for each DTO. This can be achieved by using the @XmlRootElement(name = "elementName") annotation on each DTO, where "elementName" is a unique name for each DTO.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "dto1")
public class DTO1 {
    @XmlElement
    private String field1;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "dto2")
public class DTO2 extends DTO1 {
    @XmlElement
    private String field2;
}
```

By using unique XML element names for each DTO, you can avoid the deserialization issues and still maintain the same protocol for the frontend. The frontend would need to be updated to use the new element names, but this change should be minimal and should not affect the overall functionality of the application.

Alternatively, you could consider using different media types for each DTO. For example, you could use MediaType.APPLICATION_XML for DTO1 and MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON for DTO2. This would allow you to keep the same @XmlRootElement names for both DTOs while still differentiating them based on the media type. However, this approach would require more changes to the frontend, as it would need to be able to handle both XML and JSON.